# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - Ant is not building OpenTok jar into APK

Tags: android, ant, teamcity, opentok

Been getting an issue with the [OpenTok library](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/android/).

I've followed the instructions on their page and have put the .jar file and the .so files in the libs folder as instructed.

Now I've got a bit of a weird setup for my project.

We've got an application that uses a Library. The Library basically has all of the functionality in it, including other .jar files which work fine, as the Library is used by two applications which do slightly different things. The library is where the .jar and .so for OpenTok are contained.

Now when I run this setup on Eclipse, everything works fine. But when I run it on a build that Ant has produced it will build successfully but I get the following error when I try and access the functionality.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4219): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opentok from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sps.smc.SMC-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.sps.smc.SMC-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
E/AndroidRuntime( 4219):        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4219):        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4219):        at com.opentok.android.Session.<clinit>(Session.java:51)
```

I am assuming this might have something to do with the .jar and .so using native functionality which Ant is having some trouble dealing with.

I've tried putting the .jar and .so into the applications that end up using the library but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Java issue. Make sure eclipse is using the same version of Java as your ant build. For example, `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7`

Answer (score 0):

In the libs directory, change the name of the directory: armeabi into armeabi_v7a. It worked for me.